# DNS NS record setup

Tags: domain-name-system

I have the following problem:

- Let's say my domain is at `foo.com` which has cname to `xxx.bar.io`
- `bar.io` has NS record which points to AWS' name servers

During an outage of some `io` root servers, which happens time-to-time, my DNS setup stops working.

Here is a question: can I add NS record for `bar.io NS some-aws-ns.com`into my `foo.com` and will it fix the issue? Assuming all requests then should go via `some-aws-ns.com` omitting root server for `io`. Or I'm wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't declare any records for completely other domains. If a *recursive* DNS server doesn't know `example.net.`, it starts asking root servers for `net. NS` in order to get `example.net. NS` from it and eventually your `example.net. A` records from these *authoritative* name servers. This has nothing to do with `example.com` whether or not it has `CNAME` records pointing to the *canonical* name in `example.net`.

However, you can completely avoid this problem with `.io` root servers by using individual `A` records on `example.com`, instead of your `CNAME` records pointing to another domain.